# how to force numeric keyboard on mobile with input type ="text"

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

if I use input type="number" the default keyboard is numeric on mobile. But I prefer type="text", because my input is PIN which can begin with 0, and I need some other attributes: minlength, maxlength, pattern

I wonder if it's possible to force numeric keyboard on mobile for other type than numeric and tel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `<input type="text" pattern="\d*" inputmode="numeric">`. This will cause the numeric keyboard to appear.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need... Thank you!